# Excel Row formula end of month every nth row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to create a schedule takes a date and adds 1 month every 4 lines.  My schedule starts on the 7th row (6th row is the header).  The date should always be the end of the month date.  Here's the formula I have so far:

=DATE(YEAR(Add_Date),MONTH(Add_Date)+INT((ROW()-ROW(A$6)-1)/2),DAY(Add_Date))

I can't seem to figure out how to have the result show the end of month properly, it seems to want to add 30 days instead of 1 month.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your date to always be the end of the month, use the `EOMONTH` function (unless you have a very early Excel version that lacks this).

I assume `Add_Date` is some date someplace in your workbook.

```
=EOMONTH(Add_Date,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/4))
```

or, with dynamic rows-per-month:

```
=EOMONTH(Add_Date,INT((ROWS($1:1)-1)/Rows_Per_Month))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When there is a date in A7, please try the formula in A8, then pull down:

```
=DATE(YEAR($A$7),MONTH($A$7)+INT((ROW(A7)-6)/4)+1,1)-1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Emily.  Your response helped me solve what I was attempting to accomplish.

=DATE(YEAR(Add_Date),MONTH(Add_Date)+INT((ROW()-ROW(J$6)-1)/Rows_Per_Month)+1,1)-1

I did make the change to Rows_Per_Month to allow the amount of rows to be dynamic.  I also did need to leave the Add_Date since the starting date is coming from another sheet.

Thanks again.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than a answer,, solving a problem is always a good point,,  especially when yourself solves the issue,, please [edit] the post and remove unwanted text, also add some sample data to make it more meaningful !

Answer (score -1):

*Since you have not provided sample data therefore, I would like to suggest two possible methods:*

[image]

**Method 1:**

- Get increment in adjacent column.
- Formula in cell `AG26`:

  ```
  =IF(MOD(CELL("row",AF25),4)=0, DATE(YEAR(AF26),MONTH(AF26)+1,DAY(AF26)),"")
  ```

---

**Method 2:**

- Get increment in same column.
- Formula in cell `AH27`:

  ```
  =DATE(YEAR($AH$26),MONTH($AH$26)+INT((ROW()-25)/4),DAY($AH$26))
  ```

**N.B.**

- *Here `-25` is editable, and it should according to the Row number of Source Date (i.e. in `AH26`).*

---

- If you don't like calculating Row number then use this formula in cell `AH27`.

  ```
  =DATE(YEAR($AH$26),MONTH($AH$26)+INT((ROW()-ROW(AH$25))/4),DAY($AH$26))
  ```
- *Adjust cell references as needed.*